# php gettext is not displaying French accents correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, gettext

If I use French accents on my page in html, they display correctly as in:

> avons été l'icône de Montréal pour la cuisine indienne traditionnelle.

However, after using gettext, the same phrase displays as:

> avons �t� l'ic�ne de Montr�al pour la cuisine indienne traditionnelle<

The po file shows it correctly and everything is coded in utf-8 as far as I can tell. I've viewed the .mo file in HEX and the values are correct, for example C3 A9 for "é".

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Followed [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91650)?

Comment: You can use the function `utf8_encode()` to display it correctly

Comment: 1) Why do you assume the text is encoded in Latin1? 2) If it is, then there's a root encoding issue somewhere that should be fixed. 3) If this works, this may work for French, but will not help at all with non-Latin1 languages, so is a bad monkey patch.

Comment: How would I use "utf8_encode()" with "gettext()"?

Comment: I wound up using html unicode strings in the .po file. For example I used **&eacute;** instead of **é**. To do easily I made a php script to do the substitutions.
The script uses the following php function:

    function accent2html($text)
    {
  $text = htmlentities($text, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
     $text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
     return $text;
    }

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and after checking thousand times different things (HTTP encoding header, in-page encoding header, .po file encoding, etc.), this resolved it:

```
$gtDomain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($gtDomain, "/path/to/gettext/folder/Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($gtDomain, 'UTF-8'); //This was the missing piece.
```

And this is a more complete excerpt:

```
$gtLocale = 'fr_FR';
$gtLocaleEnc = "$gtLocale.UTF-8";
//echo "gtLocale #$gtLocale# gtLocaleEnc #$gtLocaleEnc#<br />";

putenv("LANGUAGE=" . $gtLocale); //First priority!
putenv("LANG=" . $gtLocale);
putenv("LC_ALL=" . $gtLocale);
putenv("LC_MESSAGES=" . $gtLocale);
//echo "env LANG #", getenv('LANG'), "#<br />";
//echo "env LC_ALL #", getenv('LC_ALL'), "#<br />";
//echo "env LC_MESSAGES #", getenv('LC_MESSAGES'), "#<br />";

$gtIsLocaleSupported = setlocale(LC_ALL, $gtLocale);
$gtIsLocaleSupportedT = setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $gtLocale);
//echo "gtIsLocaleSupported #$gtIsLocaleSupported#<br />";
//echo "gtIsLocaleSupportedT #$gtIsLocaleSupportedT#<br />";
//echo "getcwd #", getcwd(), "#<br />";

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$gtDomain = "messages";
//The following means that the catalog "messages" 
//e.g. for the locale fr_FR is to be in:
///path/to/gettext/folder/Locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo:
bindtextdomain($gtDomain, "/path/to/gettext/folder/Locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($gtDomain, 'UTF-8'); //This was the missing piece

//Now set the current catalog to be "messages" in order to test it:
textdomain($gtDomain);
//If your .mo for fr_FR translates "Reference" as "Référence",...
echo _("Reference"); //...then this should yield "Référence".
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. bind_textdomain_codeset($gtDomain, 'UTF-8'); is what I needed